# Criar um dicionário no Python recebendo valores do banco de dados

Tags: sql, python

Depois de acessar o banco de dados e ter o query desejado no caso:

```
...
c =  conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT `tb1`.`Nome`, `tb1`.`Apelido` FROM tb1')
```

Como crio um dicionário em python referente ao meu comando acima?

```
dict = {Nome:'Apelido'} ...
?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode tentar usar o cursor.fetchall(), explicado [aqui](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html).

Ele retorna uma lista de tuplas com o resultado do teu SELECT. A partir disso, é fácil transformar em dicionário.

Você ainda pode passar um parâmetro (dictionary = True), que pra mim ainda não funcionou. [Veja aqui](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursordict.html)

Bom trabalho!

Comment: Muito bom o parâmetro dictionary = True. Irei usá-lo.